# Geometry proof problem (high school)

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

I have an upcoming chapter test and this was one of the practice problems. Can someone guide me?

Given: Isosceles $\triangle ABC$ with $AB$ congruent to $AC$;  $AD$ is not a median of $\triangle ABC$. 
Prove: $AD$ does not bisect $\angle A$.

My idea is to use proof by contradiction but I'm not sure if my thinking is right.

Comment: Is $D$ necessarily a point on $BC$?

Comment: yes it is Sp3000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do, and this might be what you meant, is to prove the *contrapositive*, which is kind of like a proof by contradiction, but is more direct. We take as given the isosceles triangle with $AB \cong AC$, with $D$ on $BC$, prove that

Assume $AD$ bisects $\angle A,$ then prove that AD is a median of $\triangle ABC$.

If you can do this, you will have proven

(I) IF $AD$ bisects $\angle A,$, THEN $AD$ is a median of $\triangle ABC$.

Proving (I) is equivalent to proving, with the initial "givens", that

(II) if $AD$ is NOT a median of $\triangle ABC$, then AD does not bisect $\angle A$.

Do you think you can do this? (Think SAS).

Comment: Note: The contrapositive of "IF P then Q" is "If NOT Q, then NOT P" and the two statements are logically equivalent.

Comment: If I start out saying that $AD$ does bisect $\angle A$ then I can show that $\triangle ADB$ and $\triangle ADC$ are congruent by SAS.But then I would need a contradiction that shows that the assumption is not compatible with the given. We are doing indirect proofs. I've never done a proof by contrapositive.

Comment: Well then your assumption would be assuming BOTH that $AD$ is not a median of $\triangle ABC$, and assuming that $AD$ *does* bisect $\angle A$. Then with your conclusions, you'll know BC = DC, (that D is the midpoint of BC), and you'll find a contradiction - something that is incompatible with "$AD$ is not a median of $\triangle ABC$."

Comment: Thanks I understand what you're saying

Comment: You're welcome. Does this make sense. I think you know exactly what you need to do. So yes, your thinking/intuition was "spot on".

Comment: Nice Amy :+))))

Answer (score 2):

I would prove it using the contrapositive.

You want to prove this: If AD is not a median of $\triangle ABC$
(which is the same as D does not bisect BC),
then AD does not bisect $\angle A$.

The contrapositive, which is logically equivalent is this:
If AD  bisects $\angle A$
then AD is a median of $\triangle ABC$
(which is the same as D bisects BC).

This should be easy to prove
(SAS).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to proof by contradiction, then you can do this.

Assume that $AD$ is not median and bisects $\angle BAC$, as it's shown on the picture below

[image: triangle]

then, according to SAS ($AB = AC$ by statement of the problem, $\angle BAD = \angle DAC$ by assumption and $AD$ is common edge) $\triangle BAD \cong \triangle ADC$ which means $BD = DC$ as well, which in turn means that $D$ is median. Contradiction.